# Converting List of List to Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading in data (as show below) into a list of lists, and I want to convert it into a dataframe with seven columns. The error I get is: `requirement failed: number of columns doesn't match. Old column names (1): value, new column names (7): <list of columns>`

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I fix it?

Data:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2
```

Code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("er").master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val erResponse = response.body.toString.split("\\\n")
val header = erResponse(0)
val body = erResponse.drop(1).map(x => x.split(",").toList).toList
val erDf = body.toDF()
erDf.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this `number of columns doesn't match` error because your `erDf` dataframe contains only one column, that contains an array:

```
+----------------------------+
|value                       |
+----------------------------+
|[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]       |
|[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2]|
+----------------------------+
```

You can't match this unique column with the seven columns contained in your header.

The solution here is, given this `erDf` dataframe, to iterate over your header columns list to build columns one by one. Your complete code thus become:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("er").master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val erResponse = response.body.toString.split("\\\n")
val header = erResponse(0).split(", ") // build header columns list
val body = erResponse.drop(1).map(x => x.split(",").toList).toList
val erDf = header
  .zipWithIndex
  .foldLeft(body.toDF())((acc, elem) => acc.withColumn(elem._1, col("value")(elem._2)))
  .drop("value")
```

That will give you the following `erDf` dataframe:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      a|      b|      c|      d|      e|      f|      g|
|     a2|     b2|     c2|     d2|     e2|     f2|     g2|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```